# How to implement universal-image-loader in separate thread?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

In the project universal image loader was used for displaying gridview,viewpager.while I need to integrate the offline mode for app,
I need to download and store images on disc in separate thread and then when displaying gridview ,viewpager images should load from disc.
How to implement universal-image-loader in separate thread? I have tried it but after some time the activity exits it's like the thread and loading universal imageloader exceeds the app cache,I mean somethings goes wrong. I have seen different discussions  but I really need to download via UIL in separate thread.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 1) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        processBitmaps();

    }
}


public void processBitmaps() {
   fulls = Application.getOnThisDeviceFulls();
    if (fulls != null && fulls.size() > 0) {

        for (int index = 0; index < fulls.size(); index++) {
            Full full= fulls.get(index).getFull();
            ArrayList<Page> pages =fulls.get(index).getPages();
            for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {

                String pagePattern = ...

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                loadUILImage();


                if (j == pages.size() - 1) {
                 Application.removeFullOnDevice(index);
                }
                if (resetIndex) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (resetMagazineIndex) {

                magazineIndex = 0;
                Log.i("magazinethread ", resetIndex + "");
                resetIndex = false;
                break;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Universal-Image-Loader loads images on a separate thread for you.  You shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: Pls add relevant code and logcat here ...

Comment: I have tried without thread,but  when I go over the pages to get imagepath and the load,from time to time I receive new fullList and I need to start go over fullslist from 0 index,otherwise without thread when I go over list and add get the all list paths UIL keeps queue of paths to load images,I mean with thread I could control the queue of loading images,as it the queue is changing over time

Answer (score 0):

The [simple example](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in the documentation works thread based:

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, 
                                  View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
    }
});
```

Use the `ImageLoaderConfiguration` in order to define particular threading parameters:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .threadPoolSize(3) 
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        ...
```

From the [JavaDoc](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/downloads/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-javadoc.jar):

> `public void loadImage(String uri, ImageLoadingListener listener)`
>
> Adds load image task to execution pool. Image will be returned with
>   ImageLoadingListener.onLoadingComplete(String, android.view.View,
>   android.graphics.Bitmap) callback}.  NOTE:
>   init(ImageLoaderConfiguration) method must be called before this
>   method call